# Ruby on Rails: Learning ActionController class - Question on $:.unshift activesupport_path and autoload method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Inside ActionController class (rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.lib) I found several weird code. I don't really have a mentor to learn Ruby on Rails from, so this forum is my only hope:

Question #1: Could anyone help me explain these lines of codes?

```
begin
  require 'active_support'
rescue LoadError
  activesupport_path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../activesupport/lib"
  if File.directory?(activesupport_path)
    $:.unshift activesupport_path
    require 'active_support'
  end
end
```

Especially the line with $:.unshift activesupport_path

In my thought, it tries to require active_support class, and if that doesn't work, it looks if activesupport_path is a directory, if it is, then . . . I totally lost it.

Question #2: What autoload method is for?

```
module ActionController
  # TODO: Review explicit to see if they will automatically be handled by
  # the initilizer if they are really needed.
  def self.load_all!
    [Base, CGIHandler, CgiRequest, Request, Response, Http::Headers, UrlRewriter, UrlWriter]
  end

  autoload :Base, 'action_controller/base'
  autoload :Benchmarking, 'action_controller/benchmarking'
  autoload :Caching, 'action_controller/caching'
  autoload :Cookies, 'action_controller/cookies'
  .
  .
  .
```

Question #3: If I later find a method I don't understand what for, how is the best way to find out? As for that autoload method case, I tried to find it across my project (I have my Rails code frozen there) but couldn't find any clue. I searched for "def autoload". Am I doing things wrong? Is my IDE, TextMate just doesn't cut it?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have time to answer all that, but #2: autoload is ruby's way of doing lazy loading ~ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for a file to be required you have to ensure that the path to it is in the Ruby `$LOAD_PATH` variable. This is has a short-hand version `$:` for legacy reasons, inheriting this from Perl.

When you call `require`, the interpreter looks for a `.rb` file in each of the paths given there until it finds a match. If it finds one, it is loaded. If not you get an exception.

Often you will see lines like this in files:

```
# script/something

# This appends "script/../lib" to the $LOAD_PATH, but this expands to
# something like "/home/user/project/lib" depending on the details of
# your installation.
$: << File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'lib'), File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

You can use standard Array modifiers on `$LOAD_PATH` like `unshift`, `push`, and `<<`.

The first block of code is attempting to load `active_support` and only if that fails does it go about modifying the `$LOAD_PATH` to include the likely location of this file based on the path to the file making the require call. They do this because typically all gems from the Rails bundle are installed in the same base directory.

The reason for using `unshift` is to put that path at the highest priority, inserted at the front of the list. The `<<` or `push` method adds to the end, lowest priority.

When you `require` a file it is loaded in, parsed, and evaluated, an operation which can take a small but measurable amount of time and will consume more memory to hold any class or method definitions inside the file, as well as any data such as string constants that may be declared. Loading in every single element of a library like ActiveRecord using `require` will require a considerable amount of memory, and this will import every database driver available, not just the ones that are actually used.

Ruby allows you to declare a class and a path to the file where it is defined, but with the advantage of not actually loading it in at that moment. This means that references to that class don't cause script errors in other parts of your application that make use of them.

You will often see declarations like this:

```
class Foo
  # Declare the class Foo::Bar to be defined in foo/bar.rb
  autoload(:Bar, 'foo/bar')
end
```

When using `autoload` you need to keep in mind that the class name is always defined within the scope of the module or class declaring it. In this example `Bar` is within `Foo`, or `Foo::Bar` using Ruby naming conventions.

When you make use of the `Bar` class, the `foo/bar.rb` file will be required. Think of it as creating a stub `Bar` class that transforms into the real class once it's actually exercised.

This is a great way of keeping a lot of options open, with many different modules ready to use, but without having to load everything into memory up front.

As for the third question, searchable documentation like [APIDock](http://apidock.com/) will help you try and find more information on methods. The distinction between Ruby and Rails is often blurred, so you may have to check through both to be sure. Rails adds a lot of methods to core Ruby classes, so don't take the listing of methods available to be complete on either side. They work in conjunction.

Sometimes it pays to search for `def methodname` when trying to find out about where `methodname` originates, although this covers only conventional declarations. That method may be an alias from a mechanism like `method_alias` or may have been dynamically created using `define_method`, you can never really be sure until you dig around. At least 90% of the methods in Rails are declared the conventional way, though, so most of the time a simple search will yield what you want.

Comment: wow, awesome complete answer, I really owe you one, thanks a lot! I am sure this would help many RoR beginner who aims to be more advanced developers.